# Unable to run the command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, composer

I trying to install the composer..... tried to run this command

```
sudo apt install curl php-cli php-mbstring git unzip
```

on ubuntu 18.10 .... I got this message displayed on cmd

```
sudo apt install curl php-cli php-mbstring git unzip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
unzip is already the newest version (6.0-21ubuntu1).
curl is already the newest version (7.61.0-1ubuntu2.2).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php-mbstring : Depends: php7.2-mbstring but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: What is the status on this?  Is this solved?

Answer (score 0):

Are you on unstable? What version of php do you have installed?

You, can install php7 if you only have php5.

Furthermore, you can use use `php7.2-mbstring` as a package name for `apt` to ensure you get 7.2.